# Access current driver in Katalon Studio

Tags: appium, katalon-studio

I am trying to use Appium's TouchAction inside of Katalon Studio. I need to pass the Appium driver into the TouchAction() constructor. When Katalon runs a test, the driver already exists. Is there a way to access the driver that is created by Katalon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below function to access current driver of Katalon Studio:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileDriverFactory
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver

AppiumDriver<?> driver = MobileDriverFactory.getDriver()
```